# How to calculate the turnover number?

Tags: enzymes, enzyme-kinetics

I understand that Kcat (turnover number) = Vmax/total enzyme concentration.
However the formula I have been given is Kcat = specific activity/molecular mass of enzyme.

What is the relationship between these two different formulas - why do they give the same answer?

Definition of Kcat that I am using: specific activity * molecular mass of the enzyme
Specific activity = units of enzyme/ mass of protein in mg

Comment: Are you sure your formula refers to the molecular weight of the enzyme, and not the total mass of enzyme in the reaction? It would be helpful to post a copy of the question you are working on.

Comment: @J-- I've uploaded the formulae

Comment: Please do not upload text as images. It is impossible to index and it discriminates against people with sight defects.

Comment: Yes, and especially don't post images of sideways text.

Comment: Do not post images as questions. There cannot be indexed by the search and pose problems for persons with sight problems. Please correct this to avoid closure and subsequent deletion of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Let's do some unit analysis:

$\pu t$ = time

$\pu U$ = units = $\mathrm{mol_{product}/t}$

$\pu s=$ specific activity $\mathrm{= U/g_{protein}}$

Therefore:

$\mathrm{s = mol_{product} / (g_{protien} \times{t})}$

Your sheet says:

$\mathrm{k_{cat}= s \times MW_{protien}}$

And we know that:

$\mathrm{MW_{protein} = g_{protein} / mol_{protein}}$

Substituting definitions of specific activity and MW<sub>protein</sub>:

$\mathrm{k_{cat}= mol_{product} \times g_{protein} / (g_{protien} \times t \times mol_{protein})}$

$\mathrm{k_{cat} = mol_{product} / (mol_{protein} \times t)}$

Cancel out the molar terms:

$\mathrm{k_{cat} = t^{-1}}$

This yields the correct unit for kcat ($t^{-1}$). You can think of this as the number of product molecules formed per enzyme molecule, *per unit time*.